# HTML Listbox similar to this one

Tags: html, listbox, styles

Does anybody know where can I find a html list-box like to one shown in the below screenshot?

http://s3.picofile.com/file/7582998488/search.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap can provide the skins you need. It's just applied with CSS. More info can be found here: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html